# Netbeans fail - Application already exists in path /

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat8

I have troubles running java webapplications in netbeans. 
Everytime i press run i'm getting the following message:

**undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/test
FAIL - Unable to delete [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/test]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.
In-place deployment at /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/test/build/web
deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext4496745316361475551.xml&path=/test
Deployment is in progress...
FAIL - Application already exists at path /test
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/test/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)**

Anyone hasany idea how to fix this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Windows had a problem deleting the old copy of the app. Try deleting it manually. You might have to stop NetBeans to convince Windows to allow you to delete the directory, after that I think it'll be fine.